# D3.JS 'zoom' undefined

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, zooming

I am trying to make simple zoom/pan solution, using this code

```
  var map = document.getElementById('map'),
      svg = d3.select('#map')
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
            }))
            .append('g');
```

But at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOGA5.png) moment it gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoom' of undefined
```

In html I have just this:

```
<svg id="map" class="map" viewBox="0 0 8000 2000"></svg>
```

P.S. Inspired by [this](https://coderwall.com/p/psogia/simplest-way-to-add-zoom-pan-on-d3-js)

Comment: I started with d3 today, so I won't leave a real answer yet. You using version 4 of the api? Looks like `d3.behavior.zoom` moved to `d3.zoom`.

Comment: d3 v4 doesn't have d3.behavior,zoom. Its just d3.zoom

Comment: Also with the v4 you can use directly `svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)` as the event triggered on zooming now has a *transform* object with a `toString` method ([Doc.](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom-transforms))

Comment: i am having the exact same issue. did you ever get a solution?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald as far as I remember, I had to use older version of d3

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald the solution, as mentioned above, is to use `d3.zoom` instead. This works for v4.

Answer (score 11):

Try Below code:
in v4 of d3.js,
**d3.behavior.zoom** changed to **d3.zoom**

```
var svg;

svg= d3.select("svg")
        .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
              svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
         }))
        .append("g");
```